# how does Stackoverflow serve ads?

Tags: discussion, advertising

How does Stackoverflow serve ads? All ads have an "http://engine.adzerk.net" link followed by a list of keywords. I went to th adzerk website. There wasn't much documentation there as to how to use adzerk for your site.

Answer (score 4):

I'm the founder of Adzerk - we just moved out of private beta into a public beta. If you are interested in using Adzerk on your site you can fill out the email box on the [pricing page](http://adzerk.com/pricing/) and we will be sending out more information soon.

Adzerk is an ad server built for usability, speed, and flexibility. Keep in mind that we aren't an ad network - we don't sell ads we just deliver them. (StackOverflow sells all of their own ads directly)

Comment: James, Can adzerk deliver from adsense if there is no inventory available? I think that's something many would be very interested in.

Comment: Absolutely - you can serve any network as back-fill (AdSense, Rubicon, Pubmatic, etc).