# Spam in sponsored links?

Tags: support, advertising, spam, sponsored-tags

I was just on the [google-app-engine](/questions/tagged/google-app-engine) tag, which has a sponsered links section on the top. For the longest time, these were all documentation and mailing list links from Google. Now, a new one has appeared (at the bottom):
[image: What the...]
This link leads to (DO NOT CLICK, I have no idea what's here because of AdBlock):

```
http://engine.adzerk.net/redirect/0/22813/2775/0/00000000000000000000000000000000/0
```

This is not a link from Google. I don't think it's a link from Stack Exchange either. So, either we, or Google, has been hacked by some spammers. What's going on?!?

EDIT:
The rest of the sponsored App Engine links lead to the same add site, with a slightly different URL.

EDIT:
It's the same on every Google sponsored tag, but not other ones, like Facebook.

Comment: Well, it does lead [to a Google page about hiring engineers](http://www.google.com/about/jobs/locations/mountain-view/client-facing/technical-sales/solutions-architect-cloud-platform-mountain-view.html). It's odd that it's send over adzerk, but nothing impressive to see here.

Comment: You might have caught it while it was being update. The links were failing a couple minutes ago but work fine now.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby: Really? I guess adblock just freaked as soon as it saw `adzerk`. But why would google be sending they're URLs over an ad site, especially on a community for programmers?

Comment: @Mat: They still lead to an ad site.

Comment: It's SE's add provider, nothing really surprising there those are sponsored links.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stack Exchange uses [adzerk](http://www.adzerk.com/) as its [advertisement delivery system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81813/how-does-stackoverflow-serve-ads), and the link in question goes to [this Google job posting](http://www.google.com/about/jobs/locations/mountain-view/client-facing/technical-sales/solutions-architect-cloud-platform-mountain-view.html). There's nothing malicious going on here, it's just tracking clicks on sponsored links.

I'm not sure why the links on Facebook sponsored tags don't follow the same pattern, but this behaviour is the same for [other non-Google sponsored tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cuda) as well.

Comment: I guess AdBlock was just freaking when it saw adzerk. Thanks.