# Is Adzerk safe / legitimate?

Tags: support, advertising

So I accidently clicked on an Adzerk link on [Super User](http://superuser.com) to be redirected to `careers.stackoverflow.com`, which is a Stack Exchange site. I'm just wondering, are these Adzerk links on the site safe to click? They're not cheap malicious ads?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81813/how-does-stackoverflow-serve-ads (bottom line: yes, safe to click :))

Answer (score 13):

Adzerk is the company paid by Stack Exchange to handle advertisement *delivery* on Stack Overflow, SuperUser and Server Fault. Ad *content* is handled by Stack Exchange directly.

The URL just contains Base-64 encoded JSON data with a cryptographic signature to ensure integrity; the JSON data contains:

```
{
    "av": 414,
    "at": 17,
    "cm": 841,
    "ch": 1178,
    "cr": 8211,
    "di": "78ad0a89f3f44367b0391d08ae47ccd4",
    "dm": 1,
    "fc": 14855,
    "fl": 2423,
    "ip": "<redacted IP address>",
    "kw": "windows-7,x-user-registered",
    "nw": 22,
    "pc": 0,
    "pr": 1568,
    "rt": 1,
    "rf": "http://superuser.com/posts/800685/edit",
    "st": 8476,
    "uk": "ue1-054c1ba141d844808c3d11e666412335",
    "zn": 47,
    "ts": 1408637336815,
    "ur": "http://careers.stackoverflow.com/"
}
```

e.g. it contains information as to where you came from, the time, your IP address, etc; all stuff 'publicly' extractable and commonly aggregated by advertisers.

The footer on every page links to the [Stack Exchange privacy policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy) that outlines exactly what Stack Exchange (and by extension, Adzerk) do with this information.

For what it's worth, Adzerk is also used by Reddit and jQuery.com, and they published their [company values](http://adzerk.com/about), including *Users have a right to privacy when using the internet*. It's a scouts honour promise, but it is nice to see their intent published.

Comment: Okay, so it doesnt contain any bloat like those doubleclick ads? Its just a simple redirect which extracts my ip/os name for the advertisers?

Comment: @Keyes: Stack Exchange prides itself in making advertisements relevant and would not allow bloat.

Comment: `privacy policy that outlines exactly what Stack Exchange (and by extension, Adzerk) do with this information`

[Note that this is Scout's honour and not legally binding.](http://scholar.google.com/scholar_case?case=8287630509855765415)